# Show that there exists a basis $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of $U$ such that the projection on $y_i$ on $\langle u \rangle$ is $2u$ for $i=1,\dots,n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ be a non-zero vector of an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $U$ where $n\geq 2$. Show that there exists a basis $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of $U$ such that the projection on $y_i$ on $\langle u \rangle$ is $2u$ for $i=1,\dots,n$

Suppose that there exists such a basis.
Then by the formula of orthogonal projection 
$$\frac{(y_1,u)}{(u,u)}y_1=\dots=\frac{(y_n,u)}{(u,u)}y_n=2u$$
But this implies that 
$$(y_1,u)y_1=\dots=(y_n,u)y_n$$
This contradicts the fact that the set is linearly independent right?

Comment: your formula is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** If $U=\mathbb R^n$ and $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ is standard basis , then projection of $y_i$ on $u=(1,1,...,1)$ is   $$\frac{u.y_i}{u.u}u=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$$
And it's true for $\alpha u$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $u \in U$ (normed vector space) that there exist basis of $U$ s.t projection of any elements of this basis on $u$ is $\alpha u$ .